# Writing a spreadsheet using CFspreadsheet to avoid error this file might be corrupted

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am trying to figure out how to add my html table to a CFspreadsheet to show in excel. All the examples online that I have found are not as crazy as mine (only a simple one basic query). Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. This is what I have been able to figure out **so far for my spreadsheet**:

```
<cfset objSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetNew()>
<cfset filename = expandPath("./myexcel.xls")>

<!--- Create and format the header row. --->
<cfset SpreadsheetAddRow( objSpreadsheet, "Associate Name,Location,Checklists Generated by Associate,Checklists Generated by Selected Location(s),Associate Percentage of Location Total" )>
<cfset SpreadsheetFormatRow( objSpreadsheet, {bold=true, alignment="center"}, 1 )>


<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=#filename#"> 
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.ms-excel" variable="#SpreadsheetReadBinary( objSpreadsheet )#">
```

**My table trying to convert:**

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <th><strong>Associate Name</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Location</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Checklists Generated by Associate</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Checklists Generated by Selected Location(s)</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Associate Percentage of Location Total</strong></th>  
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <cfoutput query="GetEmployeeInfo">
      <tr>
          <td><cfif rnA EQ 1><strong>#assoc_name#</strong></cfif></td>
          <td><cfif rnL EQ 1>#trans_location#</cfif></td>
          <td>#checklistsByAssocLoc#</td> 
          <td>#assocChecklistsByLoc#</td> 
          <td>#DecimalFormat(totalChecklistsByAssocLocPct)# %</td> 
          <!---<td> rnA: #rnA# | rnL: #rnL# | rnTotAssoc: #rnTotAssoc# </td> --->
      </tr>
      <cfif rnTotAssoc EQ 1> 
      <tr> 
          <td>Associate Total</td> 
          <td></td> 
          <td>#totalChecklistsByAssoc#</td> 
          <td>#totalAssocChecklistsByAllFilteredLoc#</td> 
          <td>#DecimalFormat(totalChecklistsByLocPct)# %</td>
      </tr>
      </cfif>
    </cfoutput>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**My crazy queries!:**

```
<cfquery datasource="#application.dsn#" name="GetEmployeeInfo"> 
    SELECT s4.associate /* Associate's ID */ 
        , s4.assoc_name /* Associate's Name */ 
        , s4.trans_location /* Associate's Location */ 
        , s4.checklistsByAssocLoc /* Gives you a count of Checklists by Associate for a specific Location. */ 
        , s4.assocChecklistsByLoc /* Gives you a count of Total Checklists by All Associates in a Location. */ 
        , s4.totalChecklistsByAssoc /** Gives you a count of Total Checklists by Specific Associate in All Locations. */ 
        , s4.totalAssocChecklistsByAllFilteredLoc /* Gives you a count of Total Checklists by Specific Associates in All Locations. */ 
        , CASE WHEN ( coalesce(s4.assocChecklistsByLoc,0) > 0 ) THEN (CAST(s4.checklistsByAssocLoc AS decimal(8,2))/s4.assocChecklistsByLoc) * 100 ELSE 0 END AS totalChecklistsByAssocLocPct /* This gives you a percent of associate location checklists over count of checklists by Associate in a Location. */ 
        , CASE WHEN ( coalesce(s4.totalAssocChecklistsByAllFilteredLoc,0) > 0 ) THEN (CAST(s4.totalChecklistsByAssoc AS decimal(8,2))/s4.totalAssocChecklistsByAllFilteredLoc) * 100 ELSE 0 END AS totalChecklistsByLocPct /* This gives you a percent of Total Associate Checklists in All Locations over count of Checklists by All Associate in All Locations. */ 
        , s4.rnA /* Placeholder for a record to display the Associate Name. */ 
        , s4.rnL /* Placeholder for a record to display the Location. */ 
        , s4.rnTotAssoc /* Placeholder for the last Associate Location row. The next row should be an Associate Total. */ 
    FROM ( 
    SELECT s3.* 
        , SUM(s3.assocChecklistsByLoc) OVER (PARTITION BY s3.associate) AS totalAssocChecklistsByAllFilteredLoc /* Gives you a count of Total Checklists by Specific Associates in All Locations. */ 
    FROM ( 

    SELECT s2.* 
        FROM ( 
            SELECT a.assoc_name 
                , s1.associate 
                , s1.trans_location 
                , s1.checklistsByAssocLoc 
                , s1.assocChecklistsByLoc 
                , s1.totalChecklistsByAssoc 
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s1.associate ORDER BY s1.associate, s1.trans_location) AS rnA /* Placeholder for a record to display the Associate Name */ 
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s1.associate, s1.trans_location ORDER BY s1.associate, s1.trans_location) AS rnL /* Placeholder for a record to display the Location */ 
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s1.associate ORDER BY s1.trans_location DESC) AS rnTotAssoc /* Placeholder for the last Associate Location row. The next row should be an Associate Total. */ 
    FROM ( 
    SELECT c.associate 
        , c.trans_location 
        , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c.associate, c.trans_location) AS checklistsByAssocLoc /* Gives you a count of Checklists by Associate for a specific Location. */ 
        , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c.associate) AS totalChecklistsByAssoc /* Gives you a count of Total Checklists by Associate in All Locations. */ 
        , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c.trans_location) AS assocChecklistsByLoc /* Gives you a count of Total Checklists by All Associates in a Location. */ 
    FROM cl_checklists c 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tco_associates a ON c.associate = a.assoc_id 
        AND a.assoc_id IN ( <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.EmployeeName#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" list="true" />  ) /* SELECTED ASSOCIATE IDs */ 
            WHERE c.[DATE] >= <cfqueryparam value="#date1#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" /> /* SELECTED DATES */ 
                AND c.[DATE] <= <cfqueryparam value="#date2#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" /> 
                AND c.trans_location IN ( <cfqueryparam value="#locList#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" list="true" />  ) /* SELECTED LOCATIONS */ 
    ) s1 
    INNER JOIN tco_associates a ON s1.associate = a.assoc_id 
        AND a.assoc_id IN ( <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.EmployeeName#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" list="true" />  ) /* SELECTED ASSOCIATE IDs */ 

    ) s2 
    WHERE s2.rnA = 1 OR s2.rnL = 1 /* There will be a final Location (rnL=1 and rnTotAssoc=1). This is the final row. */ 
    ) s3 
    ) s4 
    ORDER BY s4.assoc_name, s4.trans_location
</cfquery>
```

This is the path I was thinking but I truly dont understand calling the rows and columns. Do I even have the right idea or am I way off?

```
<cfoutput query="GetEmployeeInfo">
    <cfif rnA EQ 1><cfset SpreadsheetSetCellValue( objSpreadsheet, #assoc_name#, 2, 1) ></cfif>
    <cfif rnL EQ 1><cfset SpreadsheetSetCellValue( objSpreadsheet, #trans_location#, 2, 1) ></cfif>
    <cfset SpreadsheetSetCellValue( objSpreadsheet, #checklistsByAssocLoc#, 2, 1) >
    <cfset SpreadsheetSetCellValue( objSpreadsheet, #assocChecklistsByLoc#, 2, 1) >
    <cfset SpreadsheetSetCellValue( objSpreadsheet, #DecimalFormat(totalChecklistsByAssocLocPct)# %, 2, 1) >
    <cfif rnTotAssoc EQ 1>
        <cfset SpreadsheetSetCellValue( objSpreadsheet, 'Associate Total', 2, 1) >
        <cfset SpreadsheetSetCellValue( objSpreadsheet, '', 2, 1) >
        <cfset SpreadsheetSetCellValue( objSpreadsheet, #totalChecklistsByAssoc#, 2, 1) >
        <cfset SpreadsheetSetCellValue( objSpreadsheet, #totalAssocChecklistsByAllFilteredLoc#, 2, 1) >
        <cfset SpreadsheetSetCellValue( objSpreadsheet, #DecimalFormat(totalChecklistsByLocPct)# %, 2, 1) >
    </cfif>
</cfoutput>
```

Also tried:

```
<cfoutput query="GetEmployeeInfo">
    <cfset SpreadsheetAddRow( objSpreadsheet, "<cfif rnA EQ 1>#assoc_name#</cfif>,<cfif rnL EQ 1>#trans_location#</cfif>,#checklistsByAssocLoc#,#assocChecklistsByLoc#,#DecimalFormat(totalChecklistsByAssocLocPct)# %" )>
    <cfif rnTotAssoc EQ 1>
        <cfset SpreadsheetAddRow( objSpreadsheet, "Associate Total,'',#totalChecklistsByAssoc#,#totalAssocChecklistsByAllFilteredLoc#,#DecimalFormat(totalChecklistsByLocPct)# %" )>
    </cfif>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: So what happens when you run that code? Include any error messages, stack traces, etc. If it is not working as you expect, explain the difference between what it does and what you want it to do. [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your final snippet ColdFusion tags will not be evaluated in a string literal. For if else statements, you could use the ternary operator to toggle some of the output. Also, if any of your data contains comma/s it'll split the data between cells. To combat this, try wrapping each cell value in quotes. This may keep your text in one cell. [Others still have had issues with this fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34210714/coldfusion-spreadsheetaddrow-how-to-get-around-values-with-commas).

```
<cfset rowNumber = 0 />
<cfoutput query="GetEmployeeInfo">
    <cfset rowNumber++ />
    <cfset rowList = "'#(rnA eq 1)?assoc_name:''#', '#(rnl eq 1)?trans_location:''#', '#checklistsByAssocLoc#,#assocChecklistsByLoc#', '#DecimalFormat(totalChecklistsByAssocLocPct)# %'">
    <cfset SpreadsheetAddRow( objSpreadsheet, rowList)>
    <cfset spreadsheetFormatCell( objSpreadsheet, {bold: true}, rowNumber, 1 )>
    <cfif rnTotAssoc EQ 1>
        <cfset rowNumber++ />
        <cfset rowList = "'Associate Total','','#totalChecklistsByAssoc#','#totalAssocChecklistsByAllFilteredLoc#','#DecimalFormat(totalChecklistsByLocPct)# %'" >
        <cfset SpreadsheetAddRow( objSpreadsheet, rowList )>
    </cfif>
</cfoutput>
```

Personally, due to slow rendering time of using many (few hundred+) `spreadsheetAddRow`s to create a spread sheet, and working with lists of string data can be a pain, I almost always place my spreadsheet data into a query object. Once the data is in a query object, it takes one call to `spreadsheetAddRows` to get the data into the spreadsheet.

```
qReportData = queryNew("Name, Age",
    "varchar, integer",
    [{name: "Tom", age: 25},{name: "Dick", age: 40},{name: "Harry", age: 55}]
);
sheet = SpreadsheetNew(false);

//Add and format headers
bold = {bold: true};
spreadsheetAddRow(sheet, "Name, Age");
spreadsheetFormatRow(sheet, bold, 1);

spreadsheetAddRows(sheet, qReportData);
```

Given that some of your report data can be on multiple rows, under specific situations, you won’t be able to just export your report query, so we'll have to build a new one with code. We'll iterate over the report and generate rows in our spreadsheet query. In my example, I'll add an extra row any time the person is over the age of 40.

```
qSheetOutput = queryNew("Name, Age");
for(row in qReportData){
    queryAddRow(qSheetOutput, {
        name: row.name,
        age: row.age
    });
    if(row.age > 40){
        queryAddRow(qSheetOutput, {
            name: row.name & " is over 40"
        });
    }
}
// now writing the generated query to the spreadsheet
spreadsheetAddRows(sheet, qSheetOutput);
```

The last step will be to iterate and format the cells of the spreadsheet. As I iterate over the output I have to offset the row I'm working with by the count of headers in the sheet, witch in this example is 1. Also for this example, the extra row for a person over the age of 40 will not be bolded, and will span 2 cells.

```
for(row in qSheetOutput){
    if(!len(row.age)){
        spreadsheetFormatCell(sheet, {dataformat="@", alignment="center"}, qSheetOutput.currentRow + 1, 1);
        spreadsheetFormatCell(sheet, qSheetOutput.currentRow + 1, qSheetOutput.currentRow + 1, 1, 2);
    }
    else{
        spreadsheetFormatCell( sheet, bold, qSheetOutput.currentRow + 1, 1 );
    }
}
```

If looking at the output is too difficult to determine the correct format/s needed for the row, you could iterate over an array/s of row numbers that require a specific format/s. Once again notice I'm using the header count as an offset again.

```
dataRows = [];
messageRows = [];
for(row in qReportData){
    queryAddRow(qSheetOutput, {
        name: row.name,
        age: row.age
    });
    arrayAppend(dataRows, qSheetOutput.recordCount + 1);
    if(row.age > 40){
        queryAddRow(qSheetOutput, {
            name: row.name & " is over 40"
        });
        arrayAppend(messageRows, qSheetOutput.recordCount + 1);
    }
}
...
for(rowNumber in dataRows){
    spreadsheetFormatCell( sheet, bold, rowNumber, 1 );
}
for(rowNumber in messageRows){
    spreadsheetFormatCell(sheet, {dataformat="@", alignment="center"}, rowNumber, 1);
    spreadsheetFormatCell(sheet, rowNumber, rowNumber, 1, 2);
}
```

Here is the complete working code on [TryCF.com](https://trycf.com/gist/75397d1a26207734e71f75cef8bb5f35/acf?theme=monokai)

Comment: A spreadsheet knows the width of a cell as part of its formatting, you can use `SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth` to change the width of the field. Excel does not assume a width for the column like it would with an html table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157515/discussion-between-twillen-and-david-brierton).

Answer (score 1):

In honour of your perseverance, here is one that I did a couple of days ago.  The `visitData`, `headers`, `columns` and `title` variables were set earlier in the program because they also applied to html output.

```
<cfscript>
filePath = "d:\dw\dwweb\work\";
fileName = title  & " " & getTickCount() & ".xlsx";

sheet = spreadSheetNew("data", true);
HeaderFormat = {};
HeaderFormat.bold = true;

spreadSheetAddRow(sheet, headers);
SpreadSheetFormatRow(sheet, HeaderFormat, 1);
SpreadSheetAddFreezePane(sheet, 0,1);

for (queryRow = 1; queryRow <= visitData.recordcount; queryRow ++) {
rowNumber = queryRow + 1;
for (columnNumber = 1; columnNumber <= listLen(columns); columnNumber ++) {
thisColumn = listGetAt(columns, columnNumber);
thisValue = visitData[thisColumn][queryrow];
SpreadSheetSetCellValue(sheet, thisValue, rowNumber, columnNumber);
} // columns
} // rows

SpreadSheetWrite(sheet,filePath & fileName, true);
</cfscript>
<cfheader name="content-disposition"  value="Attachment;filename=#fileName#">
<cfcontent  file="#filePath & fileName#"  type="application/vnd.ms-excel">
```

Note the variables that I use in the last two tags.  The `<cfheader>` tag has only the name of the file, but not the path.  A mistake I was making earlier was to use just one variable which had both.  The result was undesireable filenames being sent to the user.

Comment: for filepath does this allow you to grab a table from a .htm and then loop through the fields and fill the spreadsheet? Sorry I am still super confused with all of this