# cfspreadsheet Parameter validation error

Tags: coldfusion, cfspreadsheet

I am trying to get a basic example to work using `cfspreadsheet`. But this is the error I am receiving:

> Parameter validation error for the SPREADSHEETSETCELLVALUE function.

**Code**

```
<cfset objSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetNew()>

<!--- Create and format the header row. --->
<cfset SpreadsheetAddRow( objSpreadsheet, "Location,Percent of Total Checklists,Location Total" )>
<cfset SpreadsheetFormatRow( objSpreadsheet, {bold=true, alignment="center"}, 1 )>

<!--- Populate the spreadsheet. --->
<cfset SpreadsheetSetCellValue( objSpreadsheet, 'FSC', 2, 1, "String" ) >
<cfset SpreadsheetSetCellValue( objSpreadsheet, .03, 2, 2, "Numeric" ) >
<cfset SpreadsheetSetCellValue( objSpreadsheet, 13, 2, 3, "Numeric" ) >
<cfset SpreadsheetSetCellValue( objSpreadsheet, 'OPERATIONS', 3, 1, "String" ) >
<cfset SpreadsheetSetCellValue( objSpreadsheet, 13.78, 3, 2, "Numeric" ) >
<cfset SpreadsheetSetCellValue( objSpreadsheet, 5161, 3, 3, "Numeric" ) >


<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=LS_#Dateformat(NOW(),'MMDDYYYY')#"> 
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.ms-excel" variable="#SpreadsheetReadBinary( objSpreadsheet )#">
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Comment out all the commands that use SpreadsheetSetCellValue and run the page.  If it runs successfully, uncomment each line, one at a time and run the page until you see which one is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `datatype` (String, Numeric) argument wasn't added until CF11, and is refrenced in the [adobe docs](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/spreadsheetsetcellvalue.html) under history. If you try to include the data type in CF9 and CF10 you will get the validation error.

You can see your example working on [TryCF.com](https://trycf.com/gist/22a292757ab134bb0258dcbf3e7df5d2/acf11?theme=monokai) in CF11.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46829902/writing-a-spreadsheet-using-cfspreadsheet-to-avoid-error-this-file-might-be-corr